# Taking a name and adding it to a binary tree structure

Tags: scheme

A node in this tree is a list of three items (name left right), where name is a string, and left and right are the child trees i feel like i have gotten off track is there an easy way to write this with just (define(insert name left right))

```
(define tree
     (lambda (node word)
       (cond
         ((null? node) (make-tree word))
         ((string=? word (tree-word node))
          (set-tree-count! node (+ (tree-count node) 1))
          node)
         ((string<? word (tree-word node))
          (set-tree-left! node (tree (tree-left node) word))
          node)
         (else
          (set-tree-right! node (tree (tree-right node) word))
          node))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use mutation operations, in general in Scheme we avoid them, in this case in particular is easy (and recommended) to build a new tree as we go. And, why the count? this problem has nothing to do with adding numbers. Also notice that the definition `(insert name left right)` doesn't make much sense, we want to insert a *word* starting from a tree's root *node*; `left` and `right` aren't useful as parameters. Let's start again from scratch.

```
(define (insert node word)
  (cond ((null? node) (make-tree word '() '()))
        ((string=?  word (tree-word node)) node)
        ((string>=? word (tree-word node)) 
         (make-tree (tree-word node)
                    (tree-left node) 
                    (insert (tree-right node) word)))
        (else         
         (make-tree (tree-word node) 
                    (insert (tree-left node) word)
                    (tree-right node)))))
```

Comment: sorry i know it wasnt clear but is there a way to do it if the function was being called on a tree and didnt have to handle the tree itself? Basically just a function to enter one name to either the left or right side of a tree?

Comment: How can you possibly modify a tree if you don't "handle" it? And besides the above _is_ being called "on a tree".